# MFC TextOut using CString fails

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi, document-view

I use MFC TextOut to put some text on screen as follows

```
std::string myIntToStr(int number)
{
    std::stringstream ss;//create a stringstream
    ss << number;//add number to the stream
    return ss.str();//return a string with the contents of the stream
}


void MViewClass::DrawFunction()
{
    CClientDC aDC(this);
    // .. Drawing Code
    aDC.TextOut(27, 50, ("my age is " + myIntToStr(23)).c_str());

}
```

But I get error saying " cannot convert argument 3 from 'const char *' to 'const CString &'".

The documentation for TextOut shows a CString overload. I would like to use CString with TextOut as it allows me to use my myIntToStr converter. Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont necessarily have to use TextOut, if you could please suggest me an alternative that works with CString, that would work just the same. Or if you tell me how to convert int to whatever type TextOut requires, that would solve my problem too.

Comment: FWIW, C++ has a `std::to_string` function.

Comment: There is no CString in the posted code.

Comment: Could this be a Unicode issue? ie. Your project is compiled in unicode but you are trying to use Ansi strings? You could try using the wide variant of std::string and prefixing your literal with 'L'.

Answer (score 1):

The code uses `std::string's`c_str`, which returns`const char*`, not`CString`. Try

```
void MViewClass::DrawFunction()
{
    CClientDC aDC(this);
    CString s("my age is ");
    s += myIntToStr(23).c_str();
    // .. Drawing Code
    aDC.TextOut(27, 50, s);
}
```

or just use [CString::Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

```
void MViewClass::DrawFunction()
{
    CClientDC aDC(this);
    CString s;
    s.Format("my age is %d", 23);
    // .. Drawing Code
    aDC.TextOut(27, 50, s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you use function `myIntToStr` to convert an int to a string elsewhere in you code, and that you current problem is how to display a C++ `string` with TextOut.

You could simply create a CString in the stack initialized from the `std::string` that way :

```
void MViewClass::DrawFunction()
{
    CClientDC aDC(this);
    // .. Drawing Code
    CString age(("my age is " + myIntToStr(23)).c_str());
    aDC.TextOut(27, 50, age);

}
```

As it is created on the stack, it will automatically vanish at the end of the method and you have not worry about allocation and deallocation.